# Count Down in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, time

I've been looking for solution to my problem but all I found is "Timer",
I need to show the price as countdown in ascending order in a textfield.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear. You wish to count down, but in an ascending order?
Did you mean to increase the value as time passes by or decrease it?

I've written some code to help you, whatever may be your requirement.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property int price;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _price = 1000;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updatePrice) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)updatePrice
{
    _price = _price-10; // Here I'm reducing the price by 10, add to increase the price

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",_price]];
    });
}
```